# Unpair bluetooth Android with dependency service

Tags: c#, android, bluetooth, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I need to unpair bluetooth after a installation has been made and i've tried this code:

```
string address;

    public void UnpairDroid()
    {
        BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.DefaultAdapter;
        BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevice = bluetoothAdapter.GetRemoteDevice(address);
        var mi = bluetoothDevice.Class.GetMethod("removeBond", null);
        mi.Invoke(bluetoothDevice, null);
    }
```

It throws an exception when it reaches that code because object (string address) is not set. Do I need to verify the address towards the bluetooth api?

Ive spend hours to find a solution but no ideas left. Please help! Thanks.

Is this a better approach?

```
BluetoothDevice device;
private void unpairDevice() {
try {
    Method m = device.getClass()
        .getMethod("removeBond", (Class[]) null);
    m.invoke(device, (Object[]) null);
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
}}
```

I have not gotten that code to work though..

Comment: The second way is java code, its content is the same to your first way c# code. Make sure the `address` is not `null` and the the device which id is the `address` is connecting to your device.

Answer (score 0):

Local address can be got by [bluetoothAdapter.Address](http://iosapi.xamarin.com/) , remote address can be got by

```
    BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.DefaultAdapter;
    List<BluetoothDevice> bondedDevices = new List<BluetoothDevice>(bluetoothAdapter.BondedDevices);
    if (bondedDevices.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (BluetoothDevice device in bondedDevices)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("Name="+device.Name+" Address="+device.Address);
            BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevice = bluetoothAdapter.GetRemoteDevice(device.Address);
            var mi = bluetoothDevice.Class.GetMethod("removeBond", null);
            mi.Invoke(bluetoothDevice, null);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, use `BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevice = bluetoothAdapter.GetRemoteDevice(device.Address);` if the `device.Address` is not null.